# Rspec with inherited_resources is redirecting instead of rendering on failed update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I am new to both rspec and inherited_resources.  I have a simple resource, Contact, that has a name field.  The controller has no special functionality.

```
class ContactsController <  InheritedResources::Base 
  actions :all, :except => [:show]
end
```

I have written specs for create and index just fine, using mock_model.  However, when using mock_model on update, it couldn't find the contact when putting.  So, I switched to using real models:

```
describe "PUT update" do
let(:contact) { Contact.create(:name => "test 1") }

it "edits the contact" do
  contact.name = "#{contact.name}-edited"
end
context "when the contact updates successfully" do
  before do
    contact.stub(:save).and_return(true)
  end
  it "redirects to the Contacts index" do
    put :update, :id => contact.id, :contact => contact
    #assigns[:contact].name = "test 1 - edited"
    response.should redirect_to(:action => "index")
  end
end

context "when the contact fails to save" do
  before do
    contact.stub(:save).and_return(false)
    contact.stub(:update_attributes).and_return(false)
    contact.stub(:errors).and_return(:errors => { :anything => "anything" })
  end
  it "renders the edit template" do
    put :update, :id => contact.id, :contact => contact
    response.should render_template :edit
  end
end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) ContactsController PUT update when the contact fails to save renders the edit template
   Failure/Error: response.should render_template :edit
   Expected block to return true value.
   # ./spec/controllers/contacts_controller_spec.rb:82:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I inspect the status_code, it's a 302 redirect to /contacts/:id.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really common problem when people start using mocks in controller tests. You're stubbing methods on an object that's local to the spec. When you access your controller with `put`, InheritedResources is calling `Contact.find(params[:id])` and getting back its own object, *not* the object you want it to.

Your spec fails because `update_attributes` runs without issue and redirects back to the object's `show` page.

The general fix for this is to also mock the `find` method on your model so that it instead returns your stubbed-out object instead of a different one.

```
Contact.should_receive(:find).and_return(contact)
contact.should_receive(:update_attributes).and_return(false)
put :update, :id => contact.id, # etc.
```